# How can I delete a directory in a Zip file using .NET?

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

How would I delete a directory in a .zip and all the files in it (preferably using DotNetZip)?

Right now I'm running through all the files in the zip, but it doesn't work:

```
foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
{
    //If the file is in the directory I want to delete
    if(e.FileName.Substring(0, 9) == "FolderName/")
    {
        zip.RemoveEntry(e.FileName);                          
    }
}
```

Is there a better way, if not, how would I make this work?

Comment: -1 really? I researched for a few hours. I was just stuck on this couldn't figure it out...

Comment: Can't help but notice you retrieve a substring of length 9 chars, only to compare it to one of 11 chars, so it will *always* return false. (or is this just an example string?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First tought. Don't loop with foreach while removing elements from the collection.
I will try in this way

```
for(int x = zip.Count -1; x >= 0; x--) 
{ 
    ZipEntry e = zip[x];
    if(e.FileName.Substring(0, 9) == "FolderName/") 
        zip.RemoveEntry(e.FileName);                           
}
```

However, looking at the methods of the ZipFile class, I noticed the method:
SelectEntries that return a ICollection. So I think it's possible to do:
EDIT: Use overloaded version SelectEntries(string,string)

```
var selection = zip1.SelectEntries("*.*", "FolderName");
for(x = selection.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    ZipEntry e = selection[x];
    zip.RemoveEntry(e.FileName);                           
}
```

removing the loop on all entries in the zipfile

Comment: That worked great. Why do you think mine failed? (Also, if possible, is there a way to delete the folder now?)

Comment: If you remove an item from a collection while you're enumerating through it, it's hardly surprising you'll had seen issues. This rather neat approach iterates through the collection by index, in reverse order, which avoids the issue.

Comment: @Chris what error did you get when you tried removing the file?

Comment: I love you guys, Haha. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Remove folder? Not necessary. If I remember well, removing all the "foldername/*.*" files will cause the 'folder' to disappear

Comment: @Greg "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not be executed."

Comment: @Chris, so as you've already learned, the runtime doesn't like you changing the contents of an enumerable while you're enumerating it. If you think about it, you can imagine it could cause all kinds of weirdness.

Comment: I get an error saying, can't apply index on Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry for line, selection[x];

Comment: jeez, this seems like a lot of work. There should be a RemoveDirectory method

Comment: @TheUnrealMegashark Why don't you ask your own question? You could reference this question and tell everyone what error do you get.

Comment: Most people said you had to unzip it first... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904973/delete-folder-from-jar-while-treating-as-a-zip

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple way to do this:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(@"C:\path\to\MyZipFile.zip"))
{
    zip.RemoveSelectedEntries("foldername/*"); // Delete folder and its contents
    zip.Save();
}
```

Documentation here http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it as follows

```
using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(@"C:\path\to\MyZipFile.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    zip.Entries.Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("Foldername")).ToList()
        .ForEach(y =>
        {
            zip.GetEntry(y.FullName).Delete();
        });
}
```

Note : If all the files from the folder is deleted then the folder will be automatically removed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete the directory and all nested child entries, I used

```
var sel = (from x in zip.Entries where x.FileName.StartsWith(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) select x.FileName).ToList();
foreach (var fn in sel)
{
     zip.RemoveEntry(fn);
}
```

Note that the path must end with a slash, like `dir/subdir/`