# How do I remove a specific folder with files in it from a zip using the Dotnetzip library?

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I need to remove one folder called "META-INF". It contains some files. How can I delete that folder, along with all the files in it, without typing all of their names? I can't extract all the files, delete the directory with all the files, and then pack the zip again, because the zip has many files (~1800).

Comment: Is RemoveEntry() not working?
Edit: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855155/how-can-i-delete-a-directory-in-a-zip-file-using-net
Possible duplicate?

Comment: Nice to hear that, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this:

```
 int x;
 for (x = 0; x < zip.Count - 1; x++)
 {
     ZipEntry e = zip[x];
     if (e.FileName == "META-INF/")
     {
         zip.RemoveEntry(e.FileName);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var matches = fileSelector.SelectEntries(yourZipFile,"META-INF");
for(int i = 0;i < matches.Length; ++i)
{
    yourZipFile.RemoveEntry(matches[i].FileName);
}
```

Comment: Sorry its not working...

Comment: @GemHunter1 It seems that solution suggested by Janes is working for you but he is also pointing to RemoveEntry(), that is what I have used within my code :)

Comment: And now as I see, the solution he pointed out and mine are nearly identical :)

Comment: I used that first code, not that second... And these are not same.